Get the link to website when I click on Window Toast Notification of Chrome/Brave Browser
I'm trying to get Window Toast Notification Info using winrt with Python, got trouble at finding the link on the click action of that Notification.
Below is my code.
import asyncio
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications as notifications
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications.management as management


# Function to monitor Windows notifications
async def monitor_notifications():
    listener = management.UserNotificationListener.get_current()

    await listener.request_access_async()

    print("Monitoring notifications...")

    while True:
        try:
            # Get the list of current notifications
            notifications_list = await listener.get_notifications_async(1)
            for notification in notifications_list:
                app_name = notification.app_info.display_info.display_name
                title = notification.notification.visual.bindings[0].get_text_elements()[0].text
                body = notification.notification.visual.bindings[0].get_text_elements()[1].text

                # Create a message with the notification details
                message = f"App: {app_name}\nTitle: {title}\nBody: {body}"
                print(message)

                # Remove the notification from Action Center
                listener.remove_notification(notification.id)

            # Wait for a while before checking again
            # await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'ERROR: {e}')


# Run the notification monitor
asyncio.run(monitor_notifications())

I can get all the content info for example with this picture I can get result
App: Brave  Title: Cobie  Body: I just remembered when FTX crashed
example input
Now I wanna get the link to that website if I click on that Toast Notification, I've read the docs but can't seem to find it, anyone have idea on how to do that or is that even possible?
